# Proper way to display separators in between labels and not after

Tags: jsf

I have a collection I want to display using the `<ui:repeat>` JSF tag.

What would be a proper way to add separators between the elements of the collection?

Because obviously if I do :

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.myCollection}" var="toPrint">
   #{toPrint.property}, 
</ui:repeat>
```

the last one will have a comma after it though it is the last.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.myCollection}" var="toPrint" varStatus="status">
   #{toPrint.property}#{status.last ? '' : ','}
</ui:repeat>
```

More info about [varStatus](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html).